# How to fix ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s)

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I am really new to python trying to run a linear regression using sklearn, when I try to train the model:

```
regressIt.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

It throws the following exception:

```
ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 546)) while a minimum of 1 is required.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You have a 2-D array with no rows and 546 columns, so essentially it's empty. You need to include your full code and raw data that reproduces this error

Comment: Thanks, here is what I have so far.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
#Get the data
colNames = ['price', 'lotsize']
df = pd.read_csv("Housing.csv")
Y = df.price.tolist()
X = df.lotsize.tolist()
#reshape it
X=np.array(X).reshape((1,-1))
Y=np.array(Y).reshape((1,-1))
#training/testing sets
X_train = X[:-250]
X_test = X[-250:]
# Create linear regression object
regressIt = linear_model.LinearRegression()
# Train the model 
regressIt.fit(X_train, Y_train)
#Show it
print( str(round(regressIt.predict(Y))) )

Comment: Edit your code into your question and format the code

Comment: Add the DATA and the full Code

Comment: <code>import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
#Get the data
colNames = ['price', 'lotsize']
df = pd.read_csv("Housing.csv")
Y = df.price.tolist()
X = df.lotsize.tolist()
#reshape it
X=np.array(X).reshape((1,-1))
Y=np.array(Y).reshape((1,-1))
#training/testing sets
X_train = X[:-250]
X_test = X[-250:]
Y_train = X[:-250]
Y_test = Y[:-250]
# Create linear regression object
regressIt = linear_model.LinearRegression()
# Train the model 
regressIt.fit(X_train, Y_train)
#Show it
print( str(round(regressIt.predict(Y))) )
</code>

Comment: @rob can u help me what i'm doing wrong here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296542/python-code-errors-out-with-value-error-for-forecast-data

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured it out
     
     `X=np.array(X).reshape((-1,1)) Should be this instead of ((1,-1)) Not sure why yet?
     Y=np.array(Y).reshape((-1,1))
     #Also this
     print(str(regr.predict(X_test)))`

Answer (score 0):

```
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3)
# don't keep the testing data 0 i gave 30% for example,
# for this add the next line in import
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.